# Need to stop alert on interval

Tags: javascript

My problem is that End button is not working and my alert is still showing like I have never clicked end button

```
<form><input type="button" value="StartAlert" onclick="haf()"></form>
<form><input type="button" value="EndAlert" onclick="wuf()"></form>
<script>
function haf()
{
var wtf = window.setInterval(function() { alert('rekt')} , 1000);
}
</script>
<script>
function wuf()
{
window.clearInterval(wtf);
}
</script>
```

Comment: Your `wtf` variable isn't scoped properly. Define it outside of the function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just a little fix and it will works as you expect. Move the declaration of `wtf` variable out of your `haf()` function. When you declared it inside the function, it became just a local variable accessible only inside that function. By defining the variable outside you make it global and so then accessible also to the `wuf()` function.

```html
<form><input type="button" value="StartAlert" onclick="haf()"></form>
<form><input type="button" value="EndAlert" onclick="wuf()"></form>
<script>
var wtf;
function haf()
{
wtf = window.setInterval(function() { alert('rekt')} , 1000);
}
</script>
<script>
function wuf()
{
window.clearInterval(wtf);
}
</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to declare your interval variable `wtf` at a higher scope as it currently will only exist within your `haf()` function :

```
<script>
    var wtf;
    function haf(){
        wtf = window.setInterval(function() { alert('rekt')} , 1000);
    }
</script>
<script>
    function wuf(){
        window.clearInterval(wtf);
    }
</script>
```

Scoping it outside of the function will make it accessible to calls within other functions, so now when you call your `wuf()` function, it will actually be able to see `wtf` and will be able to stop the interval.